# i want to fetch product by catefory

Tags: django, django-views

[image]

I want to display products according to their category, but I encounter a problem that I could not solve
I don't know where the problem is, although I tried to solve it, but to no avail

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home, name="home"),
    path('collaction', views.collactions, name="collactions"),
    path('collaction/<str:slug>/', views.collectionsview, name="collectionsview"),
]
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'store/index.html')

def collactions(request):
    Categorys = Category.objects.filter(status=0)
    context = { 'Categorys':Categorys}
    return render(request, 'store/layout/collaction.html', context)

def collectionsview(request, slug):
    if(Category.objects.filter(slug=slug, status=0)):
        products = product.objects.filter(category__slug=slug)
        category_name = Category.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
        context = {'products':products, 'category_name':category_name}
        return render(request, "store/products/index.html", context)
    else:
        return redirect('collections')
```

html collaction

```
{% extends 'store/layout/main.html' %}

{% block content %}
    
    <h1>collaction</h1>
    <div class="row">
        {% for item in Categorys %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <a href="{url 'collectionsview' item.slug}">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="category-image">
                                <img src="{{item.image.url}}"/>
                            </div>
                            <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>  
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you forget the `%` when using the `url` template tag. The right syntax is `{% url 'collectionsview' item.slug %}`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `%` in your url tag.

```
<a href="{% url 'collectionsview' item.slug %}">
```